# Is getting a specific App Engine entity by key, when the key has a parent key, an ancestor query?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need up-to-date consistency, not eventual consistency, so it seems like I should use an ancestor query. However, can App Engine not tell that when in Java I call

```
datastoreService.get(myKey)
```

when myKey has a parent key, that's effectively an ancestor query? Isn't the parent key of myKey an implicit ancestor restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consistency model is only relevant for queries. A `get` is not a query, it's a simple read. They are always strongly consistent.

Comment: Thanks - where is this documented?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview ("Strong consistency for reads and ancestor queries")

Answer (score 0):

Actually, App Engine datastore can be thought of as a key-value table. My theory is that retrieving values directly from the key-value table is "not" subject to eventual consistency. In contrast, when you issue a query against App Engine, the query does not go to the key-value table directly but is routed to the "index" table (in order to find a key!). And you know that it takes sometime to build/update the index; hence, eventual consistency applies here.